# Throughput of the unix TCP socket

Tags: sockets, throughput

Which way of transferring a set of uniform data (for example, 100 arrays of 1000 bytes) between two computers is faster: simultaneously through multiple sockets, or sequentially through one socket?

Is throughput of the single socket limited somehow? Why can simultaneous transfer through multiple socket be faster? Has anyone compared such configurations (i can't find any reviews)?

Comment: are we talking TCP, UDP or something else?

Comment: TCP. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is worth a paper, not sure there is a single, clear and unique answer :)

Generally speaking if the two computers are connected over a WAN (i.e. The Internet :)) most probably the limiting factor will not be the throughput of the socket (TCP or UDP) on the sending host, but the network itself.
To kind of test you are talking about is often called BTC (Bulk Transfer Capacity) for a single link. BTC is mainly meaningful for a TCP connection where the packets are retransmitted by the stack, and the sliding window mechanics may slow the transmission rate if the producer/consumer speeds do not match.
Once you know the link capacity between the two hosts, having a single or multiple links might be evaluated, taking into account also other elements such as the applications architecture (single thread/multithread etc)